# You cannot proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low error when register customer in magento2

Tags: frontend, magento2, magento2.1

I have added login and register form on same login page. But i am getting this error as below

```
You cannot proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low.
```

Before i have two different pages for login and register form.  but now i had done changes in login layout file so now both form in one page but now when i registered as customer its redirect to old create url (i.e. https://mywebsite.com/customer/account/create/) and get the below error.

```
You cannot proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low.
```

My login page layout changes as follows (path : /var/www/html/abc/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magedelight_SMSProfile::js/profile-phone-validation.js"/>
        <css src="Magedelight_SMSProfile::css/smsprofile.css"/>
        <title>Customer Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customer_account_create_head_components" template="Magento_Customer::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- customer.form.login.extra -->
            <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
                <!-- <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="customer.new" template="Magento_Customer::newcustomer.phtml"/> -->
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="attribute_data" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\AddressAttributeData</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                    <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
                </block>
                <referenceBlock name = "customer_form_register">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magedelight_SMSProfile::register.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
                </referenceBlock>
                <!-- <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block> -->
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="loginButton" xsi:type="string">.action.login</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My login and register phtml files come from the below path

/var/www/html/abc/app/design/frontend/Megnor/mag110246_4/Magedelight_SMSProfile/templates

So i am not getting why redirect to old register page nd that page showing error. If anyone help me then let me know